# Default return if validate function not validated

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm building shiny application with google-auth and internationalization, so I use `googleauthr` and `shiny.i18n`. I want that the user, which registered in my app and selected certain language in next time get app in needed language, but if this user is new or user even didn't authorization he must get default language for app.

There are code of my app:

```r
# Libraries ====
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny.i18n)
library(shiny.semantic)
library(shiny.router)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(googleAuthR)
library(googlesheets)
library(kableExtra)
library(waiter)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
# Authorization ====
options(
   googleAuthR.webapp.client_id = 'appid',
   googleAuthR.webapp.client_secret = 'secretid',
   shiny.port = 7777
)
# Header ====
Header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
   title = 'App',
   titleWidth = 282.75,
   disable = FALSE,
   enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
   rightSidebarIcon = 'user',
   fixed = FALSE
)
# Sidebar ====
Sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
   disable = FALSE,
   width = 325,
   collapsed = FALSE,
   sidebarMenuOutput(outputId = 'SidebarMenu')
)
# Body ====
Body <- dashboardBody(
   includeCSS(path = 'www/style.css'),
   uiOutput(outputId = 'Home')
)
# Right Sidebar ====
RightSidebar <- rightSidebar(
   background = 'light',
   rightSidebarTabContent(
      id = 'SignInTab',
      title = 'Account',
      active = TRUE,
      icon = icon(name = 'user'),
      googleSignInUI(id = 'GoogleLogin')
   )
)
# User Interface ====
UI <- dashboardPagePlus(
   header = Header,
   sidebar = Sidebar,
   body = Body,
   rightsidebar = RightSidebar,
   title = 'App',
   skin = 'red',
   collapse_sidebar = FALSE,
   sidebar_background = 'light',
   sidebar_fullCollapse = TRUE,
   enable_preloader = TRUE,
   loading_duration = 0.25,
   md = TRUE
)
# Server ====
Server <- function(
   input,
   output,
   session
) {
   # Data ====
   Locale <- Translator$new(translation_json_path = 'translation.json')
   # User Info ====
   UserInfo <- callModule(
      module = googleSignIn,
      id = 'GoogleLogin'
   )
   User <- reactive({
         validate(need(
               expr = UserInfo(),
               message = 'You\'re not logged in'
            ))
         paste0(
            'ID',
            UserInfo()$id
         )
      })
   ReactiveLocale <- reactive({
         if(is.na(x = User())) {
            Locale$set_translation_language('en')
         } else {
            if(nrow(
                  x = gs_read(
                     ss = gs_title(x = 'Players'),
                     ws = 'PlayersList'
                  ) %>%
                  filter(PlayerID == User())
               ) != 0) {
               Locale$set_translation_language(
                  gs_read(
                     ss = gs_title(x = 'Players'),
                     ws = 'PlayersList'
                  ) %>%
                     filter(PlayerID == User()) %>% 
                     pull(PlayerLocale)
               )
            } else {
               Locale$set_translation_language('en')
            }
         }
      })
   # Body ====
   output$Home <- renderUI({
         validate(need(
               expr = ReactiveLocale(),
               message = 'You\'re not logged in'
            ))
         fluidPage(fluidRow(box(title = Locale$t('CMM001'))))
      }
   )}

# Shiny ====
shinyApp(
   ui = UI,
   server = Server
)
```

I'm trying to get default language with `ReactiveLocale` reactive function.

So if user are registered (so user id exist in my googlesheet db), then language must be from this sheet. But if user authed but not registered (user id dosn't exist in db), then language must be English.
So, these 2 cases works for me in `ReactiveLocale`
But third case - when user didn't auth doesn't work for me.
So my problem in this part of code:

```r
if(is.na(x = User())) {
   Locale$set_translation_language('en')
}
```

I tried this with `is.null` function, but it also doesn't work for me.
How I'll could change my code to get these 3 working cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is that `User()` (silently) raises an error when `UserInfo()` is falsy. That is it returns an error (not `NA` or `NULL`).

You have different options to solve this. You could move the validate part into `ReactiveLocale`, or you use a `tryCatch` approach as in this toy example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(verbatimTextOutput("out_error"),
                verbatimTextOutput("out_catch"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   get_user <- reactive(validate(need(FALSE, "User needed")))
   output$out_error <- renderPrint(get_user())
   output$out_catch <- renderPrint(tryCatch(get_user(), 
                                            error = function(err) str(err)))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: If i need update some input (e.g. `updatePickerInput()`), how I could use `tryCatch()`?

Comment: You could the use `ret <- try(your_reactive())`. If `class(ret) == "try-error"` you can react to tht.